# programmatically login pop-up authentication in C#

Tags: c#

When i open https url in IE ,it shows popup window i provide urser name and password its works fine , my question How programatically login popup window using C# ??

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Not clear what you need can you expand your question

Comment: what type of app do you want to write, windows, console or asp.net web site?

Comment: Bing "CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials" with keywords like C# or PInvoke you'd get some help.

Answer (score 0):

If your ASP.NET application uses Basic Authentication, then you your users will see this dialog. You can use Basic Authentication over https as well. But basically you need to use Basic Authentication.

See this Security Guidance document from Microsoft in order to get a better understanding of the various options you have and when to use each.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817643.aspx

Here is an example of implementing Basic Authentication using ASP.NET
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/mybasicauthentication.aspx